# How to make webpage stay the way it is when not full screen?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

http://codepen.io/davegumba/pen/yOJmNB

This webpage falls apart when it's not full screen. How do I fix this so that it stays the way it is? Thanks. It's mainly the header and the three boxes that are out of place.

```
h1 {
  color:    #F5FFFA;
  margin: 50px auto;
  letter-spacing: 12px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 65px;
  font-family: 'Lora', serif;
}

.both {
  float: right;
}

.strike {
  float: left;
}

.grapple {
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: You either learn about responsive design or hire a front-end developer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing line-height form `<h1>` should fix the header. Use `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` if you want to leave space above and below.

For the boxes you can use CSS media query to apply `float` and `margin` only if browser window is wide enough.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

You can also try flex to layout the boxes.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/